# How to live tail multiple files in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am trying to write a program that live tails all files in a directory. I will be implementing regex expressions to catch patterns in new lines added and sending an email with the new line in it if a match is found. I looked and found some really good examples...i tried implementing ExitStack for the handling of multiple files. See below:

```
def live_tail(thefile):

thefile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

while True:
    line = thefile.readline()
    if not line:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        yield str(line)

with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(file)) for file in l]
    for file in files:
        loglines = live_tail(file)
        for line in loglines:
            print(line)
```

The program runs but its stuck in an infinite loop that prints out empty lines. I tried searching for a solution but couldn't find anything... any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The design is all wrong. You need a non blocking read of the end of the file and an infinite loop around reading all the files.

Comment: Or, you may want a thread for each file. Then you can have blocking reads of each file simultaneously. Threads are good when they are blocked or sleeping.